# Elementos com appendChild no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu estou com um problema ao tentar usar o appendChild, eu tenho no código dois elementos criados com JavaScript, porém quando eu tento adicionar um a primeira div, e o outro na segunda div, aparece apenas um elemento com o texto do primeiro elemento concatenado com o texto do segundo elemento na segunda div. Eu gostaria de saber o que eu preciso fazer para que apareça um elemento na primeira div e outro elemento na segunda div. Segue o código:

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('click');

submit.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('divs');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var p = document.createElement('p');

  p.append('Olá, mundo!');
  div.append(p);
  divs[0].appendChild(div);
  
  p.append('Hello, world!');
  div.append(p)
  divs[1].appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<div class="divs" style="background: red;">
  <p>div #01</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="divs" style="background: blue;">
  <p>div #02</p>
</div>
<a href="#" id="click">Click-me</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A sua variável P, está armazenando os valores juntos, no caso tanto o 'Olá, mundo!' e o 'Hello, world!' vão ser armazenadas na mesma variável, então quando você clicar no botão, irá renderizar as duas juntos.

A mesma coisa acontece com sua variável DIV, ela esta armazenando ambos os valores juntos

Tente fazer desta maneira abaixo, caso você queira apenas a tag p, sem necessidade de uma tag div:

```
  var p1 = document.createElement('p');
  var p2 = document.createElement('p');

  p1.append('Olá, mundo!');
  div.append(p1);
  divs[0].appendChild(p1);

  p2.append('Hello, world!');
  div.append(p2)
  divs[1].appendChild(p2);
```

Caso você deseja ainda sim colocar o tag p em um container/div, você pode criar dessa maneira:

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
var p1 = document.createElement('p');
var p2 = document.createElement('p');

p1.append('Olá, mundo!');
div1.append(p1);
divs[0].appendChild(div1);
  
p2.append('Hello, world!');
div2.append(p2)
divs[1].appendChild(div2);
```

Indico você dar console log nas 4 variáveis pra conseguir visualizar melhor como funciona.

Comment: Fica muito custoso para criar uma div para cada elemento, pois eu quero reaproveitar o código, essa seria a unica solução?

Comment: Eu vou pensar em uma forma de resolver o problema com o reuso de código... Obg!

Comment: Dessa maneira que está sendo feito é a única que consigo pensar mesmo. Caso você consiga de outra forma, coloca aqui depois

Comment: @BrunoCoelho Reparou que para as duas divs o código é praticamente o mesmo, só muda o índice (0 ou 1) e o texto? Então daria para simplificar com um *loop*, por exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Leysm1ta/ - ou ainda, com um *loop* e uma função: https://jsfiddle.net/xad2qcnr/1/ - Sempre que tem algo repetitivo em que só alguns detalhes mudam, dá para generalizar desta forma (*loops* e/ou funções).